# The best way to list persons information

Tags: views, 8

I am new to Drupal and have recently started using Drupal 8. I am creating a website to act as a business profile.
One of the main content of this website is the profiles of the team members. I'd like one of the items of the main menu to be 'team members' and it should drop down into list of members.
The link of the top menu item should show a page with a summary of all members and the sub-menu items each should show a full article about a single member.

What I've tried so far is:

1- Create a user for each member, and I've added some fields as full name, etc. I'v created a view to show all users.
The problem I faced with this solution is: The view to list users cannot be seen by anonymous. The other issue is I couldn't filter this view to only show team members, for example it also shows 'admin'

2- The second approach was to create a content type called 'Team members' with fields like full name, image, etc.
I am not sure if this is the correct approach. For instance the field 'Title' is an obligatory field that doesn't make sense for a team member.

What is the correct way to add such a feature to my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stick with 1: In your view at the top where it says Access: Permissions. Click on permission and change that to Role; in FILTER, add a filter of Role.

Comment: thanks for the fast answer :)
- For my education, can I know why 2 is the wrong way to go?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about it. If the team members are not going to be login in into the site. Then approach 2 would be a good one.

Comment: Since they won't be filling in their own profiles. Admin would be filling out all their bios and stuff.

Comment: While on approach on 1. If all team members are getting a user name and pass to log in. They can fill out their bio themselves. If you have 100 team members this would save Admin a lot of time in creating and filling out each member profile.

Comment: hmm... although, you could let temporarily anonymous users add nodes of "Team Member" content type, and have them fill it out themselves without giving them a user and pass.

Comment: **Actually, approach 2 is better than 1 if you are not planning in giving team members as user name and password**

Comment: Most probably the team members won't need to log in to the site.

Comment: For approach 2, you can always change the title label to Name in the node field and in views.

Comment: Thanks again, would help if you can point to a tutorial or so that shows how to re-use the title field by renaming it.

Comment: I thought you could change node labels, but upon checking I guess you can't. Luckly, I just found this [Title Field UI](https://www.drupal.org/project/title_field_ui) module. Apprently, you can even disable titles. Give it a try.